# Iphone .How to start recording when detecting sound, and stop recording when detect silence

Tags: iphone, avplayer

How to start recording when detecting sound, and stop recording when detect silence?

Comment: Do you want to build this feature for your app or want to do this in the recorder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you should take a look at [VAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection) algorithm, this is not that much pretty easy.

Comment: No problem dude, enjoy coding and stay blessed :)